# WordPress Appearance -> Menus page is giving 504 gateway timeout error

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

This is a fresh WordPress installation. Everything was working fine until last evening when I synced around 1500 products & 150 categories (nested) for WooCommerce.

When I go into Appearance -> Menus under Admin, it wait for some time and gives a 504 gateway timeout error. It was working fine earlier, I am sure this happened because of large number of products and categories.

Frontend Shop page is loading properly in seconds without any issues with all the categories and products. So, I am sure this is not an infinite parent category loop either, may be WooCommerce does allow this itself.

I tried changing NGINX -> php.ini limits, but it did not work either.

```
max_execution_time = 120
memory_limit = 1024M
```

I tried making `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in `wp-config.php` also, but it did not output any useful information.

Copied the Chrome request as CURL and ran it on the same server itself and it also gave same error:

```
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

I wonder what I am missing here, may be any WordPress expert can help.
I installed/using the shop at `172.18.0.131` local IP, right from the beginning for testing. HTTP only, no SSL used for now.

---

EDIT: To add to it, I am using a premium theme from themeforest, changed it to Twenty Nineteen theme, but the issue persists, so I am sure that this is not theme related either.

This issue is more likely to do something with WooCommerce categories & products.

Comment: Did you change no of records per page from screen options on Menu screen ?

Comment: @AmitKumar: Thanks Amit, but I solved it by disabling a problematic menu plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Right after after posting this question, I tried to disable the `If Menu` plugin for WordPress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/

And, voila, menu page opened, with full speed.
Hope it helps someone.